# Send quiz interaction text to LMS

Tags: scorm, scorm1.2

I am trying to implement the **SCORM 1.2** in one of my LMS using the following site as a reference:

[www.vsscorm.net](http://www.vsscorm.net)

It is running perfectly. But I am not able to save the Quiz question text into the database.

The following information gets stored in database:

```
cmi.interactions.0.type
cmi.interactions.0.student_response
cmi.interactions.0.correct_responses.0.pattern
cmi.interactions.0.result
cmi.interactions.0.weighting
cmi.interactions.0.latency
cmi.interactions.0.objectives.0.id
```

I googled and get to know that the question text is stored in `cmi.interactions.n.text`, which is somehow not storing in the database.

Or maybe SCROM 1.2 doesn't support it. Since I am a newbie in SCORM, any expert advice will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cmi.interactions.n.text` does not appear to be part of the RTE specification (see "technical specification here: https://adlnet.gov/adl-research/scorm/scorm-1-2/), so is unlikely to work in a lot of LMSs. (Also see https://support.scorm.com/hc/en-us/articles/206166436-Question-Descriptions-in-SCORM-1-2 and https://support.scorm.com/hc/en-us/articles/206166696-Questions-Answers-and-how-much-you-can-report-in-SCORM-1-2-and-2004)

There isn't a great way to store this data using the SCORM 1.2 interaction model. SCORM 2004 added a "description" data point that is commonly used to store this value.

The couple of references to the `.text` element that I saw were customizations for a particular LMS.